# Python program with def function

Tags: python, function, variables, printing

My goal is as follows:

- Define a function called `elements()` with no arguments.
- Prompt user to input three favorite elements.
- Assign input to a variable called `ele`.
- Return the variable `ele`.
- Save the output of this function to a variable called `s_elements`.
- Print `"So your favorite chemical elements are Na, K, Mg"`.

So far, I have

```
def elements():
       ele = input("What are your three favorite chemical elements? ")
       s_elements=print ele
       print("So your favorite chemical elements are", s_elements)
```

I'm getting an error with `print ele` and the function is not working properly. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the exact error? I imagine some kind of syntax error. What did you intend to do with `s_elements=print ele`?

Comment: Please elaborate on "getting an error" and "not working properly". What's currently happening, *specifically*?

Comment: the error was in fact with s_elements=print ele. I intended to have what is printed with "print ele" be stored in variable s_elements

Comment: also, when running it with def elements(): the input line does not appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not following the instructions of your assignment properly.

You are supposed to return `ele`. So first:

```
def elements():
       ele = input("What are your three favorite chemical elements? ")
       return ele
```

Then, your assignment states you need to call the method and store it in `s_elements`:

```
s_elements = elements()
```

Then you are supposed to print it, which that part you have done properly:

```
print("So your favorite chemical elements are", s_elements)
```

Comment: i was about to edit again, but there's no point duplicating your answer